# QLabel() won't load a pixmap if it is a JPG image

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to have a `QLabel()` display a `pixmap` JPG image from a file (which can't be in a resource file since it is downloaded from the web), but I am having problems loading it. The code is fairly simple:

```
label = QLabel()
label.setPixmap(QPixmap("image.jpg"))
```

It works with `PNG` files, but it doesn't work with `JPG` files. I have Googled quite a bit and found that I needed to place the `"imageformats"` folder in the same folder where my script is located. However, even after doing this (and yes, `qjpeg4.dll` and others are there), it still doesn't work. I've also tried doing

```
path = r"C:\Users\Deusdies\Documents\Work\myapp\imageformats"
app.addLibraryPath(path)
```

but that didn't help either.

Again, it loads `PNGs` just fine, but it won't load `JPGs`. I've also noticed even before that it won't load `ICO` either, but I thought of it as an unrelated issue - however it doesn't seem that way now.

It is worth noting that the application is not converted to an `.exe` at this point - it is ran through `python.exe` interpreter via `PowerShell`.

My development environment is Windows 7 x64, PySide 1.1.0

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What Qt version? To see available image formats: `list = QImageReader.supportedImageFormats ()` then `print()` this list.

Comment: Are you completely sure that image is not in another format, with just the `.jpg` extension?

Comment: @dschulz: I got this: [PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('bmp'), PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('pbm'), PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('pgm'), PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('png'), PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('ppm'), PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('xbm'), PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('xpm')] Obviously the JPG is missing. Any idea how to add it? Also yes I am 100% sure it's a JPG.

Comment: I vaguely remember a blog post from a Qt developer about one specific image format plugin which was causing this kind of problems. But I think it was fixed long ago. Is your software updated?

Comment: Here's the blog post I'm talking about: [Qt Image Decoders Stepping on Each Others](http://agateau.com/2012/03/30/qt-image-decoders-stepping-on-each-others/)

Comment: Yes it's updated, using the latest stable Qt. The blog post talks about the inability to load PNGs though.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem. First, path should look like this:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Deusdies\Documents\Work\myapp"
```

(so without the "imageformats" part)

And second, I was an idiot. I created an instance of the QDialog() class before doing the `addLibraryPath()`

Comment: now there's another problem pending.. Why it worked with PNG images?? ;-)

Comment: That's because PNG support has no corresponding plugin in imageformats/, it's either included or not depending on the more general Qt configuration.

Comment: @Deusdies: is there documentation on this issue at the pyside site? I couldn't find it.