# Pyside Qpixmap not working

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pyside

I am new to pyside and I am following a tutorial at http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/widgets2/. I am trying to get an image to show in a window. It seems that I should be able to pass in a file location for a picture on my computer, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to display the file I pass in. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("C://Users//Public//Pictures//Sample Pictures//Desert.jpg")

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.show()        

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code exactly as it is works fine for me. So you must have a very specific problem! You can test with `isNull()` if the image was found and loaded but this does not explain why it wasn't loaded.

Comment: Thanks, isNull() helped and you were right my environment was messed up, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do (related topics: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739758/qlabel-wont-load-a-pixmap-if-it-is-a-jpg-image#10739758), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953352/loading-an-image-using-qpixmap/5970756#5970756))

1. Create `"imageformats"`folder in the same folder where your script is located (for example, `C:\PyProgs\imageformats`)
2. Copy `dlls` from PySide `"imageformats"` folder (`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide\plugins\imageformats` on my machine) to created folder
3. Add this code to your `main()` function:

> ```
> path = r"C:\PyProgs"
> app.addLibraryPath(path)
> ```

Full `main` code:

```
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    path = r"C:\PyProgs"
    app.addLibraryPath(path)

    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```